# Parsing HTTP GET response with wget

Tags: json, rest, batch-file, windows-7, wget

On Windows 7 here. Writing a simple monitor to test if a local app server is still healthy. The server exposes a RESTful endpoint at `http://localhost:8080/myApp/ping`.  If the server is healthy it will respond with the following JSON:

```
{
    "pong" : 1
}
```

How could I use `wget` to hit this endpoint and then parse out the "pong" response, determine if it's 1 (or non-existent, indicating failure)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little work with `FOR` should do it:

```
@echo off
set SUCCESS=0

rem get server response, find "pong", keep what comes after the :
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%i in ('wget...^|find """pong"""') do set SUCCESS=%%i

rem remove spaces
set SUCCESS=%SUCCESS: =%

if not "%SUCCESS%"=="1" echo Server down!
```

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that `"pong" : 1` will appear in its own line exactly as specified in the question, then this would work; otherwise you can modify the string you want to match specified as an argument `findstr /C:` in the code below.

```
wget http://localhost:8080/myApp/ping -O - | findstr /C:"\"pong\" : 1"
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo failure
) else (
    echo success
)
```

If you want to suppress the additional output that appears from wget and findstr commands, then you can try this.

```
wget http://localhost:8080/myApp/ping -O - 2> nul | findstr /C:"\"pong\" : 1" > nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo failure
) else (
    echo success
)
```

This redirects the verbose output written to standard error stream by wget and the output from findstr to null device.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
wget http://localhost:8080/myApp/ping -O - | findstr /C:"\"pong\" : 1" && echo Success || echo failure
```